# How to Interpret I/O on ksar, sar

Tags: io, iostat, sar

[image]

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.01     1.38  0.02  0.51     0.37     7.56    29.42     0.02   31.72   6.15   0.33
sda1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00    53.57     0.00   71.60  15.33   0.00
sda2              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00    38.77     0.00   14.13  13.56   0.00
sda3              0.00     0.20  0.02  0.11     0.30     1.23    24.46     0.00   35.65   9.69   0.12
sda4              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     2.00     0.00    8.12   8.12   0.00
sda5              0.00     1.11  0.01  0.24     0.06     5.43    44.15     0.01   44.22   7.06   0.18
sda6              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.01    39.47     0.00   51.98  17.60   0.00
sda7              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00    23.46     0.00   23.69  13.80   0.00
sda8              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.01     0.00     0.04    11.37     0.00   36.27  24.38   0.02
sda9              0.00     0.05  0.00  0.16     0.00     0.84    10.79     0.00    8.46   7.56   0.12
```

I've a graph that looks like this...Is it consider high at 12.5 /s ?How do i interpret if i/o is good or bad?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any *programming* component to this question. This should go on http://serverfault.com/